# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using Tensorflow for customize object_detection and I am facing this error while executing train.py.

[image]

Comment: Please, don't show errors or code as image, but copy it as text. Otherwise answering is really tricky for any expert willing to help you. PS: don't forget to include also the relevant code.

Comment: Please send code as text. Relevant help will be easier to get then.